# Type checking for closures and map combinations for groovy dsl

Tags: groovy, closures, dsl

i am currently testing somethings from the groovy documentation. I have stumbled across this example for a dsl.

```
show = { println it }
square_root = { Math.sqrt(it) }

def please(action) {
  [the: { what ->
    [of: { n -> action(what(n)) }]
  }]
}

// equivalent to: please(show).the(square_root).of(100)
please show the square_root of 100
```

Is there a way to ensure the type at the "of" operation is for example an int with proper syntax highlighting?

If that's not possible, what are ways to build a sentence like dsl with proper type checking?

Thank you!

ztwjsk

Comment: Return value of please could be a type instead of def. You could use an interface as a first step and use coercion so you still can use a map. There are blogs on moving from loose dsl such as this to type-checked “modern” dsl. But I don’t have a link at hand.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Using a type instead of def is a good idea. But what could be the return type? Map<Reference, Map<Reference,...> etc. ? Couldn't really get good information from the debugger as to which type I should use. Thank you!

Comment: A new interface like “interface I { J the(DoubleFunction what) }” with “interface J { double of(double) }”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By introducing an interface to use for the return type(s), you can provide the IDE with a path to infer each of the methods in your dsl.

```
import java.util.function.*

interface I { J the(DoubleFunction what) }
interface J { double of(Number n) }

def show = { println it }
def square_root = Math.&sqrt

I please(DoubleConsumer action) {
  [the: { DoubleFunction what ->
    [of: { n -> action(what(n)) }] as J
  }] as I
}

// equivalent to: please(show).the(square_root).of(100)
please show the square_root of 100
```

[image: demonstration of type inferencing]

Comment: I just tested it and it says, that it cannot cast the Map [the=...] to the interface. Syntax Highlighting is working fine though.

Comment: Do you have type checking enabled?

Comment: Do you mean CompileStatic or TypeChecked as annotation? Then yes.

Comment: You don’t need type checking or static compilation for please method. Or you can use “as” to coerce the map to the interface type.

Comment: I tried it without the annotations and without the "as" coerce and it throws "Couldnt find matching constructor for LinkedHashMap" when it tries to cast the map to the interface. I'm tried using Groovy 2.5 and 3.0

Comment: With "as" it throws "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.call() is applicable for argument types: (Double) values: [100.0]". I tried setting the closure parameter or return type but to no avail.

Comment: I updated the script to be runnable.  It prints "10.0".